# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar error using Selenium through Maven in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, maven, illegalstateexception

I have been running in to various issues while trying to configure selenium webdriver to test my spring boot application. Every time I put the selenium dependency in to my pom.xml it seems to corrupt my m2 repository, or that is what I think.

This is the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar file:/C:/Users/Usuario/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.getUrlsFromClassPathOfJarManifestIfPossible(ChangeableUrls.java:132)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls.fromClassLoader(ChangeableUrls.java:98)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:92)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.DefaultRestartInitializer.getInitialUrls(DefaultRestartInitializer.java:56)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.<init>(Restarter.java:142)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:556)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:76)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:50)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:69)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
at pe.backend.BackendApplication.main(BackendApplication.java:10)
```

I have tried cleaning my m2 repository various times and adding different versions of the dependency, but It doesn’t seem to solve it. I have also tried using clean install, but it shows a build error if I have put the selenium dependency.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar file:/C:/Users/Usuario/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar
```

...implies that one of the jars in your maven cache corrupted.

In your case, it seems the the following file got corrupted:

```
file:/C:/Users/Usuario/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar
```

---

### Solution

You need to remove the specific jar from your maven cache and re-build your application.

As you have already tried cleaning the `m2` repository various times through `clean install` but the error persists you may need to hard **delete** this particular *jar* and rebuild your application.

---

### Outro

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [Devtools startup exception](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9120)

Comment: It worked! I was doing that before, but since it kept sending other corrupted jars over and over I gave up on the like the 3rd one. This time I deleted all of the curropted jars, which where like 5. Thank you!